# 「脱ぎますか」 as 許可求め・申し出

Tags: grammar, nuances, volitional-form, form

In [this clip](https://youtu.be/dymdPycDzyw) the woman says 服脱ぎますか but she is talking about herself as opposed to asking the other party to do something. This seems to be a situation where either 許可求め or 申し出 should apply. If it is a 許可求め shouldn't てもいいですか be more apt? Or more appropriately this seems to be a scenario of 申し出, in which case I think it calls for シヨウカ形. This seems to satisfy several conditions of 申し出: 聞き手を行為者に含まず、聞き手の利益になると思われることを、話し手の行為で実行しようとする行為で、決定権は聞き手である。

So why is it not 服脱ぎましょうか？

Also, what 形 is 脱ぎますか? 終止形＋敬体＋か?

Comment: I think the form is simply masu-form + か.

Answer (score 3):

She is definitely not asking for permission. She is not particularly offering to do something for the man, either. It’s more like asking what is supposed to happen next, according to his rules, procedure, preferences, or whatever. It’s almost like a question about a fact.

ましょうか would make her sound like she is either willing to do something for him or trying to get actively involved in mutual decision making on whether or not to do it. ますか sounds more 事務的.

Comment: This is sort of a separate but definitely closely related question, and I thought I should probably ask in a comment rather than posting separately. One of the reasons I asked this question was because I always thought when the subject of the sentence and the agent of the main verb are both absent from an interrogative sentence with しますか (or other similar forms), the default is the speaker asking about the listener's action. But in the context given in the question, it is the speaker who undertakes the action. I just had a brief exchange with a friend whom I'm comfortably on タメ口 terms with.

Comment: Me: ライン交換しない？ Friend: いいよー！qr送る？ That's the entirety of the brief exchange. Normally I would interpret their question as asking if I am going to send them my QR code. But now that I have read the answers under this post, I am not so sure anymore. Part of me is inclined to think if they want to know whether I'm sending my qr, they should say 「qr送るの？」 Am I right? What do they mean exactly? Are they asking if I want them to send their QR code?

Comment: @EddieKal - It's certainly related. I would take your friend's line as "Do I send you my QR code?" The speaker is leaving the decision to something external, your preference, as in the context of this question. It sounds more passive or submissive than 「qr送ろうか？」送ろう is a volitional form after all. It represents your will, although the final decision may be left to the listener. If I want to know if you are going to send me your QR code, I would say 「qr送ってくれる（の）？」

Answer (score 1):

Of the two, it can be considered as a 申し出 and 脱ぎましょうか is okay.

Roughly, I think it is like saying *Do I...?* instead of *Shall I...?* although *Do I ...?* is much less common.

---

That said, using ーますか? as a proposal is common when the agent is the listener (opposite of 聞き手を行為者に含まず). For example:

- 試食しますか? Would you like to try it?

I guess -ますか just can be used equally when 聞き手を行為者に含まない.

- お持ちしますか. Shall I bring it (the one with right size for you)?
- お出ししますか. Shall I bring it (next dish, for example)?

-しましょうか works as well, but -しますか sounds like "Am I supposed to ..?".